# Is there a Google Chrome Extension that protects against text loss?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I have heard of an extension for Chrome that essentially saves text that you are typing in. For example if I was typing in a box such as this, often times on a refresh for example you lose text. What is the extension that can be used to make sure this text is still present in situations such as this?

I know it exists, though I do not remember the name of it, nor what to search for to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno) might be what you are looking for.

From the extension's page:

> Autosaves everything you type so you can easily recover from form-killing timeouts, crashes and network errors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [Lazarus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno). It saves web forms as you type them.

Comment: Both Dez and yourself gave me the right answer, but he gave a little more detail, so I selected him as the accepted answer.